# Restart a windows application with the original user’s privileges after some add-ons are installed

Tags: wpf, windows

In our project, the user can use the main application to install the updates or some Add-ons. After the installation is finished, the main application is started automatically. In this process, we need to ensure the main application is started with the original user’s privileges. One possible solution in my mind is like this:

1. The main application is running by a normal user, say User A;
2. User A operation on the application and starts to do the Add-on installation;
3. The application starts UpdaterLauncher, the UpdaterLauncher is running under User A’s privileges;
4. The application ends itself;
5. UpdaterLauncher starts Updater in Administrator’s privileges;
6. Updater do the Add-on installation;
7. UpdaterLauncher starts the main application with User A’s privileges, when the installation is finished.

To implement the workflow, totally 3 applications are involved: the main applilcation, UpdaterLauncher, Updater. Does anyone know if there are any better solution? Or Microsoft already has a sufficient framework to handle this?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Oh yea... its a pain in the butt every time some update wizard offers to start the application at finish just to start it with elevated administrator privileges and potentially with different user specific app data.

Comment: If you create a .bat file in the `UpdaterLauncher` and your application delete it afterwards?
then run something like this in .bat `runas /noprofile /user:user  application.exe`

https://superuser.com/questions/42537/is-there-any-sudo-command-for-windows